# Containerising a TV Server

Tags: virtualization, lxc, mediaserver, dvb

I have a server with a DVB-S2 card. For a number of reasons, I'd like to containerise/virtualise (though I'd prefer an LXD solution as I already use this) this service used to provide TV streams to my [Kodi](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux) devices. Is this possible, and if so, how does one go about making the /dev/dvd/ folder available within the container? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this, DVB devices are Unix-Character Block devices. Each element entry (but not directory) in `/dev/dvb/` has to be manually mapped across, using the command:

```
lxc config device add <container> <device> unix-char path=/dev/<device>
```

So for example, for the first demux on the first adapter into a container called `media-streamer`:

```
lxc config device add media-streamer dvb/adapter0/demux0 unix-char path=/dev/dvb/adapter0/demux0
```

You then repeat for all the devices on all the adapters you wish to pass into your container.